# Term for a logical statement that can only be proven false

Tags: logic, terminology

In logic, some statements can't be proven true, only proven false.

For example, the statement "the universe is infinite" can be disproven by discovering its bounds, say by launching a rocket that crashes into the all-encompassing, mysterious wall near a galaxy far, far away; but cannot be proven true, as the case of an infinite universe is observationally indistinguishable from the case of a universe "so large we haven't found its bounds yet".

The term I'm looking for could be viewed as equal and opposite to "unfalsifiable", in that I'm looking for a term roughly equivalent to "untruthable". Does such a term exist? Also, does the term "unfalsifiable" hold this strict interpretation of "provably true or unknowable" in logic, as I've only ever heard it used in the context of philosophy?

Comment: This reminds me of the haulting problem in computer science: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: @zkutch In comments, you have to make links this way: `[text](address)`, rather than `[text][index]` followed by `[index]: address`.

Comment: @Arthur . Thanks. Tried, ashamed, but making exactly "[text](address)" give no result. So move to answer.

Comment: I posted an answer stating that the term you were thinking of is either "satisfiable or "unsatisfiable", however on second thought this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: A *sufficient but not necessary theory/statement* is another name that is close, but not exactly what you are after. General relativity can't be proven true because we can't test all of its predictions, since it makes predictions about everything at every point in time. On the other hand, if we find a single prediction it makes which contradicts the evidence, then GR must be false. For this reason, a sufficient but not necessary theory $T\rightarrow P$ is a good fit. (Sufficient, but not necessary, because the predictions of GR could be true because of some other theory.)

Comment: This is more about logic in philosophy (of science) rather than logic in mathematics. I don't know a word, but the standard phrase would be "falsifiable but not verifiable". See [this encyclopedia entry](http://www.encyclopedia69.com/eng/d/verifiability-and-falsifiability/verifiability-and-falsifiability.htm), [this blog post](http://openscience.org/being-scientific-fasifiability-verifiability-empirical-tests-and-reproducibility/), or [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/3MRHcYtZjFY).

Comment: That said, a new question about how/whether something like this can happen in mathematical logic *would* be about mathematics.

Comment: @MarkS. That sounds like an answer. Unless someone provides something better, if you'd be willing to write that up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is more traditionally a topic in philosophy (of science) rather than logic in mathematics. I don't know of a single word for it, but the standard phrase would be "falsifiable but not verifiable". For some references for this usage, see [this encyclopedia entry](http://www.encyclopedia69.com/eng/d/verifiability-and-falsifiability/verifiability-and-falsifiability.htm), [this blog post](http://openscience.org/being-scientific-fasifiability-verifiability-empirical-tests-and-reproducibility/), or [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MRHcYtZjFY).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from our dialog in comments main phrase is

**"something that may be true, or may be false, and can be proven false if it is false, but is impossible to prove true even if it is true"**

Let me make light analysis of this sentence. Firstly we are speaking about some relation/predicate, denote it by $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{A}}$, because we want to characterize it with false or true. Then we need some proving mechanism so, generally, some other relations, axioms, predicates and logical scheme(s), denote it by $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{M}}$, using which we create proof(s), objective truth, provable truth.
Now, in  environment $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{M}}$  is possibility to forbid proof relation $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{A}}$ only when it is true.

Firstly I am interesting is this that one about which we want to speak? And second - suppose it is possible to create such $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{M}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak{A}}$, why we need them? Sorry, if some ideas are outside of strange.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm not looking for a term for something that is always true, I'm looking for a term for something that may be true and may be false, but can only ever be _proven_ false. The idea is similar to but distinct from that of [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), which show that with any axiomatically-derived version of mathematics, there will be postulates that are true, but are impossible to prove to be true even though they _are_ true. I'm looking for a term meaning "can be true or false, but can't be _proven_ true"

Comment: If I correctly understand you would like example of theorem which is independent from some existing axiom system? If so, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis is independent from ZFC. Does this make sense?

Comment: I used Gödel's incompleteness to show the difference between _objective truth_ and _provable truth_. That is, some things _are_ true but there is _no way_ to _prove_ them true. Some things _are_ false but there is no way to _prove_ them false, and philosophy refers to things that can't be proven false (whether or not they are actually false) as _unfalsifiable_. I'm looking for a word equivalent to unfalsifiable, but for the other case. A word meaning _something that may be true, or may be false, and can be proven false if it is false, but is impossible to prove true even if it is true_

Comment: Hm.. I'll try to use your terminology: in ZFC axiom system continuum hypothesis is provable truth, while any theorem, which is proved in ZFC is objective truth. As to last sentence let me think little more, please.

Comment: The negation of a tautology is called a "contradiction", but I'm pretty sure TheEnvironmentalist is looking for something which doesn't really exist in mathematics, though it's talked about [in philosophy of science](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788136/term-for-a-logical-statement-that-can-only-be-proven-false?r=SearchResults#comment7802857_3788136)

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist. As promised, add some thoughts about your last italic sentence.

Comment: The term matters in the sense that it's easy to construct, or at least plan to construct, proofs for given arguments. However, there are a number of cases wherein proofs are impossible to construct. This concept is used extensively in reference to the idea of decidability, in fact the term I'm looking for could be considered a specific, if odd, instance of [semidecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Semidecidability). The broader concept is used in logic, and extensively in theoretical computer science. It's intriguing to me that this one concept doesn't have a name

Comment: Very useful link. May be it worth to include in question. Again, I'll need some time to think about.

Answer (score 0):

The computational complexity class of such problems is defined as RE. Any problem in RE can be proven by a Turing machine to be true in finite time if it is true, but can not necessarily be proven false, even if it is false. A Turing machine is a universal machine that can solve any logical or mathematical problem that any finite algorithm or computer can solve.

For example, whether or not a Turing machine program halts (finishes its computation) or not is an example of a problem in RE. If a program is eventually computed to halt, you know the answer is yes, but if it never halts for as long as you run it, that doesn't mean it's impossible it won't halt in the future, and indeed it is impossible to prove that it eventually will halt, which is the halting problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_(complexity)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem